# Subliminal fast messages with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My mission is to create a widget for a website, a widget that asks the visitor to enter a text or an image, a duration (in Milliseconds) , and interval (in Seconds). Then there's a jQuery code that shows and hides the message depending on the duration and interval.

Suppse the user enters this data :

```
var text = "Be positive";
var duration = 30 ms;
var interval = 5000 (every five seconds).
```

It must wait for 5 seconds, then show the message "Be positive" by showing the DOM element, then waiting for 30 milliseconds to hide it again.

This is my jQuery :

```
setInterval(
    function update(){
       $('.blink_message').toggleClass('hidden');
    },30);
```

My problem is that I need to make this happen only every 5 seconds? do I have to add another setInterval outside?

Thank you

Comment: Simple way could be to use following logic: http://jsfiddle.net/39L02eje/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a way to do that:

```
var text = "Be positive";
var duration = 1000; // I changed it so you're able to see the effect better
var interval = 2000;

setInterval(function(){

    $('.blink_message').text(text);
    $('.blink_message').fadeIn('fast', function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.blink_message').fadeOut('fast');
        },duration);
    });

}, interval);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/thijs_s/fzb9nck4/

If the 30ms is really important, you should leave out the effects (fadeIn / fadeOut) and use `hide()` and `show()` instead:

```
var text = "Be positive";
var duration = 30;
var interval = 5000;

setInterval(function(){

    $('.blink_message').text(text);
    $('.blink_message').show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.blink_message').hide();
    }, duration);

}, interval);
```

One last note: if high accuracy is required, the `setTimeout` and `setInterval` functions are probably not the best option. These functions have limited resolution (they are sometimes as much as 4ms off). If you want to work on level of repaint-events (in modern browsers around 60 times per second, but depends on how busy the device's cpu is), you should look into [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame). You can achieve higher resolution timing with it.

Comment: Thank you my dear, I'm gonna give it a try

Comment: Not sure if this matters but this technique would mean that the time between the message being hidden and the message being shown again would be `interval - duration`. So if `interval < duration` then the message would never be hidden. An alternative would be to use a self-calling function - similar to the above solution but which sets a timeout of `interval` milliseconds within the callback of the `.fadeOut` function.

Comment: I tested but the problem is that the message takes longer to hide, it takes more than 30 ms. Thank you sir :)  +1

Comment: If the timing is that important, you should leave out the 'effects' and just hide and show it without any transitioning. I updated my answer so that it includes this option as well.

Comment: @T.S. yes this is what I just did, I took off fadeIn and fadeOut, and put hide and show, but the problem is still there, the message takes longer than 30 ms.

In Subliminal Messages it's very important for the user to not actually see and recognise the message,

Comment: Just modified your fiddle so that it uses a self-calling function within a timeout, so that the interval is only started once the text is hidden. See http://jsfiddle.net/ClarkeyBoy1987/fzb9nck4/1/.

Comment: @T.S. and ClarkeyBoy , thank you so much, your examples actually work with messages.

Best Answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use setTimeout instead of setInterval and use 2 different functions to hide and show message, calling the other with the right timer. It is also good idea to store jQuery objects to variables instead of creating new all the time.

```
var duration = 30;
var interval = 5000;
var blinkMessage = $('.blink_message');

function showMessage() {
    blinkMessage.removeClass('hidden');
    setTimeout(hideMessage, duration)
}

function hideMessage() {
    blinkMessage.addClass('hidden');
    setTimeout(showMessage, interval)
}

showMessage();
```

See this example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2bv4w62u/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.blink_message').toggleClass('hidden');
    },30);
},3000);
```

Comment: I tried it, but same problem as for T.S's answer, The message takes longer than 30 ms to hide, thank you anyway +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
    var text = "Be positive";
    var duration = 30;
    var interval = 5000;


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.blink_message').hide().text(text);
    setInterval(function(){
       $('.blink_message').show();
       setTimeout(function(){
           $('.blink_message').hide();
       },duration); 
    }, interval);

});
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xyedoe9f/)**

Comment: Thank you my dear, I tried but I found the same problem as for T.S's answer, the message takes longer than 30 ms to hide   +1 for your answer :)

Comment: I dont think so @SmootQ , Check the fiddle with updated values http://jsfiddle.net/xyedoe9f/2/